# How to make a sticky header with react Fullcalendar?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, sticky, fullcalendar-4

I have a react fullCalendar and I want the header of the fullcalendar will be fixed and sticky, it means when I scroll the calendar, the header will be fixed.

When I try :

```
.fc th { 
  
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
 
}
```

I get :

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You shouldn't need CSS for this. I suggest you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing, especially https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight . You can get a scrollbar just on the body of the calendar, if it doesn't fit into the height you've specified.

Comment: @ADyson I try `.fc-view-container{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}` and  `contentHeight={150}` , but, it doesn't working...

Comment: Like I said, you should not need CSS. If you simply set contentHeight as 150 then (all other things being unchanged) you'll get scrollbars. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYmZQxo

Comment: @ADyson How can I get a scrollbar on the body of the calendar?

Comment: See my CodePen demo, the link is in the comment above. It depends on what else you have been messing about with. If you don't mess anything else about, then in a simple scenario you'll get scrollbars. Remove all your CSS changes to any `fc` classes, and then try it. If there is some other complication with your scenario which prevents it from working we'll need to see a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand it fully.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, it works well ! I need to hover each timeslot for each day and when I hover it, the background of this timeslot will be blue and the time will be appeared like this :  https://ibb.co/B3WyC42 can you help me please ?

Comment: that sounds like a totally separate issue, you should ask a new question about it.

Comment: @ADyson I asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59300806/how-to-hover-each-cell-for-each-day-with-react-fullcalendar can you help me please ?